Proof of the Orthogonality of Hermite Polynomials
My question is regarding the proof of the orthogonality of Hermite polynomials. Actually, it's not quite the Hermite polynomials:
$$
\psi_n(x) = [\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n} 2^n n!}]^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} H_n(x),
$$
It's actually this function that I am willing to prove its orthogonality. As you've already noticed, $\psi_n(x)$ already normalised the Hermite function and has a proper weight function. I tried to do the procedure but it seems rather tedious. So, it would be much appreciated if you could help me with the process and correct me wherever I made a mistake.
Step-by-step Procedure
$$
\int_{\infty}^{\infty} \psi_n^*(x) \psi_m(x) dx = \delta_{nm},
$$
Henceforth,
$$
[\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n} 2^n n!}]^{\frac{1}{2}} [\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{m} 2^m m!}]^{\frac{1}{2}}\int_{\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} (-1)^n e^{x^2} [(\dfrac{d}{dx}^{\dagger})^n e^{-x^2}] (-1)^m e^{x^2} [(\dfrac{d}{dx})^m e^{-x^2}]  dx,
$$
I've treated the derivative as an operator; that's why you see the $\dagger$ above the first derivative. And from now on, I'd like to name the whole coefficient before the integral as $\Lambda$.
NOTE:
I used a certain technique to know the dagger of the derivative operator. I used group theory and some partial derivative to deduce that the $\dfrac{d}{dx}^{\dagger}$ is actually $-\dfrac{d}{dx}$ in infinite dimensional spaces.
Therefore, (Notice that I factor $(-1)^n$)
$$
\Lambda \int_{\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} (-1)^n e^{x^2} (-1)^n [(\dfrac{d}{dx})^n e^{-x^2}] (-1)^m e^{x^2} [(\dfrac{d}{dx})^m e^{-x^2}]  dx,
$$
$$
\Lambda (-1)^m \int_{\infty}^{\infty} e^{x^2} [(\dfrac{d}{dx})^n e^{-x^2}] [(\dfrac{d}{dx})^m e^{-x^2}]  dx,
$$
Now, here comes the part that I cannot quite follow. I assume that the aforementioned expression can be simplified as such,
$$
\Lambda (-1)^m \int_{\infty}^{\infty} e^{x^2} [(\dfrac{d}{dx})^{n+m} e^{-x^2}]  dx,
$$
But the problem is, I'm not capable of evaluating this any further. And I humbly ask for your guidance.
